# mdf database dosen't update data from bin\Debug folder into main folder

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is my connection string:

```
<add  name ="myConfig"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Platform.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and the class that uses that connection string:

```
internal static SqlConnection Connection
{
   get
   {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",@"C:\Users\Marius\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BidingPlatform2014\BidingPlatform2014\Platform.mdf");
      return new SqlConnection(myString);
   }
```

}

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Sever 2012.

But after my application closes data isn't saved into my primary database (database that I see under Server Explorer > Data Connection).

I think that data is stored during the execution into a copy of database located under `bin\Debug` folder.

How I update data into my original database.

Sincerely,

Comment: wht are you overwriting your default data directory which app_data?

Answer (score 0):

First, just do the call to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData just one time when your app starts and before any activity on the database. There is no need to repeat it (and has no effect once the first call to the database is made) every time you ask for the connection.

Second, |DataDirectory| should be a folder, not the full path to the MDF file

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",
 @"C:\Users\Marius\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BidingPlatform2014\BidingPlatform2014");
```